# Hide a posting on user's wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

Is it possible to hide postings on the user's wall from a facebook app, like a filter feature where the user specifies certain keywords and the app will hide all postings that contain the keywords from the user's wall?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I won't explain the entire process here as it would basically be a tutorial in how to traverse arrays. Basically, you just need to authenticate and get the User's [Feed connection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#feed) from the Graph API. This will give you a JSON array of posts representing that users Timeline/Wall.

Once you have this array, you can iterate through it and if the specific keywords exist in the content part of the JSON objects, you can choose not to display them in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can't. If the user is unable to hide a post from their profile then an app wouldn't be able to do so either. Facebook give you the option of `Hide from Timeline` to hide the post from the user's timeline, but it won't stop the post from appearing elsewhere.

You cannot delete a post from the user's timeline unless your application was the source of the message (i.e. the app created the message). FB also doesn't let you modify the user's posts:

> Privacy Policy: any non-default privacy setting must be intentionally
>   chosen by the user. You may not set a custom privacy setting unless
>   the user has proactively specified that they want this non-default
>   setting. Note that the visibility of the post will be determined by
>   the more restrictive of the user's privacy setting as well as the
>   post's privacy field

It sounds like your application is trying to **censor** the user's posts rather than hiding them on the user's request.